# Последовательное применение or и and

Tags: c++, операторы, логика, арифметика, приоритет

Почему отличается код вида

```
if (a or b or c and d and e and f)
```

от

```
if ((a or b or c) and (d and e and f))
```

Хотел правильно склонить количество предметов, но пока не поставил скобки в частях с or и and числа 12, 13, 14 почему-то "пролазили" через это условие (нужно чтобы числа заканчивались на 2,3,4, но не 12, 13, 14.

```
if ((num1 % 10 == 2 or num1 % 10 == 3 or num1 % 10 == 4) and ((num1 % 100 != 12) and (num1 % 100 != 13) and (num1 % 100 != 14)))
```

Comment: потому что у логического оператора `and` приоритет выше, чем у `or`. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Аналог: чем отличается `a+b+c*d*e*f` от `(a+b+c)*(d*e*f)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь два вопроса.

Первый — **почему**. Ответ: из-за приоритета операций. Принцип тот же, что и у отличия `a+b+c*d*e*f` от `(a+b+c)*(d*e*f)`. Приоритет `and` выше, чем приоритет `or`.

Второй — **как**. Тут я бы не стал делать такую страшную логику, ограничившись [этим](https://ideone.com/9TmYp2):

```
if (abs(num%10-3)<=1 && num%100/10!=1)
```

Ну, или, если вам так привычнее :),

```
if (abs(num%10-3)<=1 and num%100/10!=1)
```